# UISplitView in iOS 4.2 with Two Views

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I'm trying to create a UISplitView like in facebook iphone by using two UIViews on top of one another (iOS 4.2). I've a UINavigationController and when the user clicks on the leftbar button in the UINavigation controller the Top View should slide away and leave the second view. It works fine but the UINavigationController remains in the same position and I would like to slide it also with the TopView so that there is no UINavigationController on the BottomView. Is this possible? I also referred to similar questions in stackoverflow but couldn't find anything related to this particular problem. Appreciate your suggestions on this regard a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [JTRevealSidebarDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo). That is what exactly what you want.

Please let me know if you anything else than this.

Comment: Hi yes I used the JTRevealSidebarDemo but I seem to be getting a runtime exception when I integrated it to my application. [UINavigationItem setRevealSidebarDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6dba560 is the error and I followed the instructions and included all the header files. Any idea on that? Appreciate it much.

Comment: Have you integrated static library inside your project? That should be linked to the project properly. Please follow steps mentioned [here](http://mystcolor.me/post/25785144262/getting-static-libraries-into-your-ios-project)

Comment: I did not link according to those instruction but I created a sample application by including the header files and importing them to my solution. There are no compile time errors only that runtime error and I'm trying to figure out the reason for this? any suggestions? Appreciate it a lot Thanks again.

Comment: That may be because you have linked the source files and library at compile time but those are not linked at runtime. That library should be inside the application during running the application. that is the proper way of linking any library. Please follow the steps mentioned in above link. Your problem will get resolved for sure.

Comment: Thanks will try that and see Appreciate your comments much.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it right to the answer if you get your solution. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same runtime error [UINavigationItem setRevealSidebarDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6dba560 in self.navigationItem.revealSidebarDelegate = self; although I've imported the delegate. I can't seem to figure out why? Any thoughts as to what I should do? Thanks.